# Replace everything except a matching pattern in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm attempting to delete everything *but* a matching pattern using javascripts `.replace()` function and regex.

I want to save the digits from the "date" field, i.e 11 10 2021 or 9 10 2021. This regex `/[\d]{1,2} [0-9]{2} [0-9]{4}/g` matches to the date patterns, however when using `.replace(regex, '')` it replaces those digits rather than saving them. I'm just wondering how to "invert" the pattern to save the digits and replace everything else.

Example strings:

```
SURVEY API RESULT LANDING: [{"_id":"616392e41a03eed562de2e8a",
"userId":"email@gmail.com",
"date":"11 10 2021",
"timeStamp":"2:26:",
"formResponse":"Survey completed"}]
    
[{"_id":"616392e41a03eed562de2e8a",
"userId":"email@gmail.com",
"date":"9 10 2021",
"timeStamp":"2:26:",
"formResponse":"Survey completed"}]
```

Comment: Feels like it would be a lot easier to just parse the JSON and extract the `date` fields.

Comment: I would if I could - this is more an exercise in regex than anything else

Comment: Why not just use the result of `String.prototype.match(regex)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find a single date, try the following

```
`[{"_id":"616392e41a03eed562de2e8a",
"userId":"email@gmail.com",
"date":"9 10 2021",
"timeStamp":"2:26:",
"formResponse":"Survey completed"}]`.replace(/.*([\d]{1,2} [0-9]{2} [0-9]{4}).*/gms, "$1");
```

RegExp reference https://javascript.info/regexp-introduction

Comment: Thank you! I went with this but added a '?' after the first '*' as the first digit of a multiple digit date was being cut off. So the resulting regex is: 
`/.*?([\d]{1,2} [0-9]{2} [0-9]{4}).*/g`

Comment: As long as you only need to match 1 this works, although as @MrMythical suggested, `str.match(/[\d]{1,2} [/d]{2} [/d]{4}/)?.[0];` would be the more straight forward in that case. Instead of matching the full string and using a capture group.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex [exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) or string [matchAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) instead string replace

#### exec

```js
const regex = /[\d]{1,2} [\d]{2} [\d]{4}/g;
const str = `SURVEY API RESULT LANDING: [{"_id":"616392e41a03eed562de2e8a",
"userId":"email@gmail.com",
"date":"11 10 2021",
"timeStamp":"2:26:",
"formResponse":"Survey completed"}]
    
[{"_id":"616392e41a03eed562de2e8a",
"userId":"email@gmail.com",
"date":"9 10 2021",
"timeStamp":"2:26:",
"formResponse":"Survey completed"}]`;

let match;

while(match = regex.exec(str)) {
    console.log(match[0]);
}
```

#### matchAll

```js
const iterator = `SURVEY API RESULT LANDING: [{"_id":"616392e41a03eed562de2e8a",
"userId":"email@gmail.com",
"date":"12 10 2021",
"timeStamp":"2:26:",
"formResponse":"Survey completed"}]
    
[{"_id":"616392e41a03eed562de2e8a",
"userId":"email@gmail.com",
"date":"9 10 2021",
"timeStamp":"2:26:",
"formResponse":"Survey completed"}]`.matchAll(/[\d]{1,2} [\d]{2} [\d]{4}/g);

console.log(Array.from(iterator).map(m => m[0]));
```